# How to use Passenger (apache2 module) with 2+ Rails apps using each one different gemsets

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, rvm

Let's suppose I want to host 2 rails apps in the same server. I'd use RVM (installed as multiuser) and two different gemsets; suppose gemsetA for appA and gemsetB for appB.

What's the best way to manage this situation with Passenger module for apache2?
Install and compile passenger apache2 module for each gemset or create another "passenger" gemset used only for this purpose?

Thank you

PS: I've already read this [Multiple Rails sites using Passenger and VirtualHosts?](https://serverfault.com/questions/83288/multiple-rails-sites-using-passenger-and-virtualhosts) but I think he is not using RVM or, at least, he is using only one gemset.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first try installing passenger into the global gemset:

```
rvm use ree@global --default --passenger
rvm ree@global gem install passenger --version="${PASSENGER_VERSION}"
passenger-install-apache2-module --auto --apxs2-path $(which apxs2)
passenger-install-apache2-module --snippet >> /etc/apache2/conf.d/passenger.conf
```

Depending on your file permissions, you may or may not need to add the `PassengerGroup  www-data` directive.
Next, create your app gemsets:

```
rvm use ree@gemsetA --create
rvm ree@gemsetA gem install ${appA_gems}
rvm use ree@gemsetB --create
rvm ree@gemsetA gem install ${appB_gems}
# Must use .rvmrc files to change gemset per app
echo "rvm use ree@gemsetA" >> /path/to/appA/.rvmrc
echo "rvm use ree@gemsetB" >> /path/to/appB/.rvmrc
```

Finally, configure apache so each app gets it's own VirtualHost.  Use a similar set of directives ***within the VirtualHost block***:

```
    RackBaseURI /path/to/app(A|B)

    <Directory /path/to/app(A|B)>
        PassengerAppRoot /path/to/app(A|B)
        Options -MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

You may need to play around with the paths for `RackBaseURI` and `PassengerAppRoot` depending on where you've installed your app, whether it's Rack based or otherwise, or how you've configured Apache.  If in doubt, consult the [Passenger Documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html).

If you've already tried this, and couldn't get it to work, and one of the apps cannot find it's gems... you may need to look into running [Passenger Standalone](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html).